# Control Cupertino Switch value with realtime database Firebase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I need to control cupertino Switch value `isOnline` bool with `true` and `false`

I create an instance of realtime database:

```
final referenceDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
```

I create a variable to be used in method:

```
final ref = referenceDatabase.reference();
```

here is my cupertino switch:

```
bool isOnline = false;
CupertinoSwitch(
    trackColor: Color(0xff3e1646),
    value: isOnline,
    onChanged: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
        isOnline = value;                          
        ref.child('isOnline').push().set(isOnline).asStream();
        //changeState();
      });
    },
  ),
```

nothing happen
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
ValueNotifier isOnlineNotifier = ValueNotifier(false);

// ...

ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: isOnlineNotifier,
  builder: (context, isOnline, _) {
    return CupertinoSwitch(
      trackColor: Color(0xff3e1646),
      value: isOnline,
      onChanged: (value) {
        isOnlineNotifier.value = value;
      },
    );
  },
),
```